# Is it possible to execute cross-partitioned query inside trigger?

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-cosmosdb, partitioning

I have to implement auto-increment for integer property when inserting a document into Document DB collection. I wanted solved this pboblem by using pre create trigger which just find the max value and increment it. This approach works fine for simple collection but there is a problem when using partitioned one: even after specifying `{ enableCrossPartitionQuery: true }` my query is limited to the partition to which I insert the document.

```
function trigger(){
    var context = getContext();
    var collection = context.getCollection();
    var request = context.getRequest();

    // document to be created in the current operation
    var documentToCreate = request.getBody();

    //query for max value
    var filterQuery = 'SELECT value MAX(r.Id) FROM root r';

    var result = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), filterQuery, 
                                  { enableCrossPartitionQuery: true }, callback);

    function callback(err, documents, responseOptions) {
        if(err) throw new Error("Error" + err.message);

        var maxId = documents[0] || 0;
        documentToCreate["Id"] = ++maxId;
        request.setBody(documentToCreate);
    } 
}
```

So it is possible to execute a fan-out query from the trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as for stored procedures, trigger context is limited to 1 partition. 
More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data#design-for-scale (Query boundary and transactions)